# Set `store` as reducer's `state` parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, store

I'm new to Redux (and React as well) so this is probably a very elementar question, but I was unable to find a straight answer for it over the Internet.

There is a sign up screen on my app that I call `SignUp`. It is pretty straightforward and have just three inputs (`email`, `password` and `passwordCheck`) and one button (`signup`).
Thing is, I want to make my user life as simple as possible, so as `passwordCheck` is changed, I check it against `password`. If them match, `signup` is setted enabled and if them don't, `signup` goes disabled and a message is show to the user.
When I was using only React things were pretty simple - I simply made a `this.state`:

```
this.state: {
    // ... stuff
    password: "",
    passwordIsValid: false, //test password against a predicate function
    passwordMessage: "", //if the password is not valid there is a message
    passwordStyle: "", //if password is wrong i put some classes here
    passwordCheck: "",
    passwordCheckMessage: "", //the 'passwords do not match' message goes here
    passwordCheckStyle: "",
    passwordsMatch: false
}
```

And then I handled the app's state inside `SignUp`.
Now I'm using Redux as well, so I killed `this.state`, moved everything to `store` and started using reducers instead of handlers.
Everything works for `password`, but `passwordCheck` is a different story. Since I need to know Store's `password` to check it against `passwordCheck` I have been unable (so far?) to do it on `passwordCheckReducer`. Instead, I removed `passwordCheckMessage`, `passwordCheckStyle` and `passwordsMatch` from `passwordCheckReducer`, calculating this values on `SignUp`. It seems to me as a very wrong and ugly way to settle the whole thing down though.

So, instead, I would like a more elegant and Redux-like solution.

If I could get `store` to be on `passwordCheckReducer`'s `state` I would be able to set `passwordsMatch` and the others in the reducer while keeping it pure. Unfortunately, I have been unable to do it (so far?).
So, I would like to know if what I want to do is possible or if there's others, more desirables, ways to do it.

OBS1: Wherever I look on the Internet, I found the Redux official documentation on the subject of initializing state[1](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state). I do not think `preloadedState` is the way to resolve my problem, though, since it is used to iniatilize `store`, not to make it avaiable on my reducers. Instead, I simply need to have `store` - even when empty - visible to `passwordCheckReducer`.
OBS2: I know I could pass `store` as a key of `action`, but since the reducer pattern includes a `state` argument it seems redundant to me to define pass such in `action`.

Here is my Store:

```
// store.js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunkMiddleare from 'redux-thunk';
import { Reducers } from '../reducers/reducers';

const logger = createLogger();
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleare, logger);

export const Store = createStore(Reducers, middleware);
```

I'm using `combineReducers`:

```
// reducers.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { emailReducer } from './emailReducer';
import { passwordReducer } from './passwordReducer';
import { passwordCheckReducer } from './passwordCheckReducer';

export const Reducers = combineReducers({
    emailChange: emailReducer,
    passwordChange: passwordReducer,
    passwordCheckChange: passwordCheckReducer
});
```

And here is `passwordCheckReducer`:

```
// passwordCheckReducer.js
import { CHANGE_PASSWORDCHECK } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    passwordCheck: ""
};

export const passwordCheckReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    const { payload, type } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case CHANGE_PASSWORDCHECK:
            const passwordCheck = payload;
            return {
                ...state,
                passwordCheck
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};
```

Last, this is the implementation of `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
// SignUp.js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    handleEmailChange: e => dispatch(updateEmail(e.target.value)),
    handlePasswordChange: e => dispatch(updatePassword(e.target.value)),
    handlePasswordCheckChange: e => dispatch(updatePasswordCheck(e.target.value))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, when you pass your reducer to combineReducers, that reducer will receive the redux module state (so, what the initialState was, not the entire app's root state object). You don't have access to state from other reducers.

You have a few options.

I think having separate reducers for `password` and `passwordCheck` is somewhat overkill. I would go with one reducer for the entire form:

```
const initialState = {
    password: '',
    passwordCheck: '',
    // ....
}

export const signupReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    const { payload, type } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case CHANGE_PASSWORD:
            return { ...state, password: action.password}
        case CHANGE_PASSWORDCHECK:
            const passwordCheck = payload;
            if (state.password != state.passwordCheck) 
                return { ...state, passwordCheck, error: "..."}; // or something like this

            return {
                ...state,
                passwordCheck
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};
```

If you want to split things up, you can always define reducers, and call them from a parent reducer, passing the whole parent-reducer state. Something like:

```
import passwordReducer from './passwordReducer'
import passwordCheckReducer form './passwordCheckReducer'

export const signupReducer(state = initialState, action) => {
    state = passwordReducer(state, action)
    state = passwordCheckReducer(state, action)
    return state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are combining reducers, there is only one store object which stores all of the state from every reducer.

So you can access multiple reducers from one component like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  password: state.passwordChange.password,
  passwordCheck: state.passwordCheckChange.passwordCheck,
  passwordsMatch: state.passwordCheckChange.passwordsMatch
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUp)
```

Every time you update `passwordCheck` or `password`, your component's props will be updated.

So the best solution is actually to handle the passwordsMatch as a custom prop derived from the state of the two separate reducers. Something like:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const passwordsMatch = state.passwordChange.password === state.passwordCheckChange.passwordCheck
  return {
    password: state.passwordChange.password, 
    passwordCheck: state.passwordCheckChange.passwordCheck,
    passwordsMatch: passwordsMatch
  }
}
```